# Unable to write to SSHFS folder

Tags: sshfs

I've mounted a file system under SSHFS that I previously was using with NFS4 without issues.

```
user@server:/mnt/a/folder  /mnt/folder fuse.sshfs  defaults,default_permissions,_netdev,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000  0 0
```

and with NFS

```
server:/mnt/a/folder  /mnt/folder nfs4  defaults,default_permissions  0 0
```

The SSHFS folder mounts and the directory permissions look the same as they are on the remote machine, but when I try to modify/add a file on the file system that belongs to the owning user, I get a permission denied error.

Users on the remote and client machine have the same UID/GID. The file is being mounted under fstab and version 2.5-1ubuntu1 of SSHFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First log into the server, then go to the shared folder `/mnt/a/folder` and ensure you you have write access.

I tested your fstab entry and got the same error you're describing.  Then I tested the change and get the response you are looking for.

Your fstab entry:

```
[user]@server:/mnt/a/folder  /mnt/folder fuse.sshfs  defaults,default_permissions,_netdev,allow_other,uid=[user],gid=[user]  0 0
```

The change:

```
[user]@serer:/mnt/a/folder /mnt/folder fuse.sshfs  defaults,default_permissions,_netdev,allow_other,uid=[user],gid=[user]  0 0
```

Change the `[user]` to the user with `ssh` access.  Of course, don't include the brackets.

By the way, I understand you've already checked and verfied that `[user]` on the local computer and `[user]` on the remote computer has the same `uid` and `gid`, whereas they were inadvertently different for my environment.  But something is going wrong and the only detail that I can see is this which works when using the added assurance of the specific user and group ID by the name as it appears on the server.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ended up going back to NFS, but I understand what you were asking me to change and why it works.